# Another user edited a question after I already suggested an edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I proposed an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14480956) on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941563/find-inverse-of-matrix-using-bnth-power) asked recently. Two minutes later, another user proposed an edit. Mine was rejected by the [Community♦](/users/-1). Shouldn't the user who edited the question have been prevented from editing?  If not, why was his edit accepted, when mine was more comprehensive?

Comment: Did you not notice that as the first option in the duplicate suggester, or in the related sidebar?

Comment: @TinyGiant No, this isn't a duplicate. I understand why the community user rejects suggested edits. I didn't know how the user who edited the question after I did got his edit approved instead of me.

Comment: *"I understand why the community user rejects suggested edits"* conflicts with *"I didn't know how the user who edited the question after I did got his edit approved instead of me"* because the reason that the community user rejects the edit is because the other user submitted their edit which superseded yours. If you understand why the community user rejects suggested edits, how do you not understand why the community user rejects suggested edits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user started editing the question before you had submitted your edit, which is why they didn't need to review your edit before making their own changes.  Their edit was *applied* (not accepted, their edit didn't *need* to be accepted) because they have full editing privileges.  An actual edit by someone with the ability to make one without review always "wins" over someone requiring review for their edit.

Comment: "full editing privileges" Ah, there it is. Thank you.